# Why doesn't 6 / length [1, 2, 3] work in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types

Can someone explain to me why `6 / 3` works but `6 / length [1, 2, 3]` errors out?

Here's the error in REPL

```
<interactive>:20:1: error:
    • No instance for (Fractional Int) arising from a use of ‘/’
    • In the expression: 6 / length [1, 2, 3]
      In an equation for ‘it’: it = 6 / length [1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`(/)` has the type `Fractional a => a -> a -> a`, so each of its arguments has to be a value of some type with a `Fractional` instance.

Both `6` and `3` are polymorphic literals, having type `Num a => a`. Thus, `6/3` has the type `Fractional a => a`, since `Fractional` is a subclass of `Num`.

`length`, however, always returns an `Int`, and `Int` does not have a `Fractional` instance. The simplest fix is to use `genericLength :: Num i => [a] -> i` from `Data.List` instead, which can return a value of type `Fractional a => a` that is suitable for second argument to `(/)`:

```
>>> import Data.List
>>> 6 / genericLength [1,2,3]
2.0
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer. Another thing that helped me was typing :info Fractional and :info Num

Comment: You could also cast after using regular `length` with `fromIntegral (length [1,2,3])` - this is the normal method you'll see in practice.

Comment: But what if your list's length overflows an `Int`? :)

Comment: In practice, converting `length` is way more efficient. If you're worried about overflow, you can define `length64 :: Foldable t => t a -> Int64; length64 = foldl' (+) 0`, and converting from there.